# Get all static getters in a class

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, getter, es6-class

Let's say I have this class (which I using like an enum):

```
class Color {
    static get Red() {
        return 0;
    }
    static get Black() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Is there anything similar to `Object.keys` to get `['Red', 'Black']`?

I'm using Node.js v6.5.0 which means some features might be missing.

Comment: @Gothdo: `Object.keys` doesn't filter for getters either, so I assumed the OP would know how to check whether it's a getter, data property, method or something else.

Comment: @Bergi I not familiar with JS getters, I gave `Object.keys` as an example because it's the closest thing that came to my mind.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptors) and filter the results to contain only properties which have getters:

```js
class Color {
    static get Red() {
        return 0;
    }
    static get Black() {
        return 1;
    }
}

const getters = Object.entries(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Color))
  .filter(([key, descriptor]) => typeof descriptor.get === 'function')
  .map(([key]) => key)

console.log(getters)
```

You can also try this approach—it should work in Node.js 6.5.0.

```js
class Color {
    static get Red() {
        return 0;
    }
    static get Black() {
        return 1;
    }
}

const getters = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Color)
  .map(key => [key, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Color, key)])
  .filter(([key, descriptor]) => typeof descriptor.get === 'function')
  .map(([key]) => key)

console.log(getters)
```

Comment: Just a heads up that this is also a valid method for retrieving *non*-static getters, one just looks up in `Color.prototype` instead of `Color`.

Comment: `const getters = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(this)).filter(prop => prop.startsWith('get'));`