How to check if an object property is read-only (doesn't have a setter)?
Having an object that is made from a class definition:
class Something {
   get prop() {
      ...
   }
}

const s = new Something();

How to detect in code that s.prop is read-only property and cannot be set (and without trying to set it)? What I've already tried is to use Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor but it returns undefined in this case.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptors how about this one? with the 's' on the end

I've tried that already and it doesn't list class properties, like getOwnPropertyDescriptor.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39310890/get-all-static-getters-in-a-class might be a duplicate question, I think this link will help you

OK, thanks for the hint, it means I need to iterate over prototype chain then...

Your question is wrongly worded: you ask how to check if a class property is read-only; and then in your sample you create an instance of the class and ask how to check if a property of this instance is read only.

@EricMORAND Yes, you're right and thank you for the fix

Try this:
function isPropertyWritable(object, property) {
    if (!(property in object))
        throw new Error('Property not in object');

    let descriptor = Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(object, property);
    if (!descriptor) {
        let prototype = Reflect.getPrototypeOf(object);
        while (prototype) {
            descriptor = Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(prototype, property);
            if (descriptor)
                break;
            prototype = Reflect.getPrototypeOf(prototype);
        }
    }

    return 'writable' in descriptor ? descriptor.writable : descriptor.set != null;
}


That's exactly what I needed, thank you

Stolen and adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/70250484/13111630, but you can use these functions to find all the setters and getters for your class.


function listGetters (instance) {
  return Object.entries(
    Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(
      Reflect.getPrototypeOf(instance)
    )
  )
  .filter(e => typeof e[1].get === 'function' && e[0] !== '__proto__')
  .map(e => e[0]);
}

function listSetters(instance) {
    return Object.entries(
    Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(
      Reflect.getPrototypeOf(instance)
    )
  )
  .filter(e => typeof e[1].set === 'function' && e[0] !== '__proto__')
  .map(e => e[0]);
}



In your example, you can run listSetters on your Something instance to see that there's a prop getter but no prop setter.


class Something {
  get prop() {
    return "foo"
  }
}

const s = new Something();


function listGetters(instance) {
  return Object.entries(
      Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(
        Reflect.getPrototypeOf(instance)
      )
    )
    .filter(e => typeof e[1].get === 'function' && e[0] !== '__proto__')
    .map(e => e[0]);
}

function listSetters(instance) {
  return Object.entries(
      Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(
        Reflect.getPrototypeOf(instance)
      )
    )
    .filter(e => typeof e[1].set === 'function' && e[0] !== '__proto__')
    .map(e => e[0]);
}

console.log(listGetters(s));
console.log(listSetters(s));




looks good, could you provide another helper function to allow checking the instance and the property as inputs, returning true or false if that property has a setter or not? / is writable or not? I think that would more accurately answer the OP question.  This answer works though, so maybe @HankMoody can comment?

To extend this to check if a property has a setter, use: listSetters(s).Any(p => p == "prop")  but seems overkill when there's an overload to get a specific property.
